# Passing very large XML data as params in Angular 2 to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, angular

I have a text area, where user can paste any XML. Then on click of a button, the XML is sent to the server to get the response. I find, this works perfectly with smaller XMLs. But, my issue is, when I send a large XML, the Rails server log simply says

> !! Invalid
>   request

**CODE**

**Provider.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientService } from './../services/httpclient.service';

@Injectable()
export class QuestWebServiceTestProvider {
  constructor(private http: HttpClientService) {}

  getResponseXML(params) {
    return this.http.get('/api/v1/get_response_xml?request_xml=' + params["request_xml"]);
  }
}
```

**Component.ts** (this passes the XML read from textarea to provider)

```
getResponse() {
  let requestXml = this.requestXmlElement.nativeElement.value.trim();

  if(requestXml.length > 0) {
    let requestXmlJson = encodeURI(requestXml);

    this.<provider>.getResponseXML({request_xml: requestXmlJson).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

What is the best way to send larger XMLs?

Comment: There are many points where your query_string might be truncated(browser, front web server, Rails app server) and you got your "Invalid request". So, you have to use HTTP `POST` method to send large fields. Something like `return this.http.post(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, for the typo in the question. I actually use `POST` request.

Thanks [Pavel Mikhailyuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8098012/pavel-mikhailyuk) for pointing it.

This is how I fixed it:

Instead of framing the query params manually as:

```
...get_response_xml?request_xml=' + params["request_xml"]
```

I pass the XML as options to `HTTP POST`:

```
let options = {request_xml: params["request_xml"] };

return this.http.post('...get_response_xml?, options);
```

This seemed to work !!!